# Dynamics CRM 2011 - The plug-in type could not be found

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I am trying to deploy a plugin to an on-premise Dynamics CRM 2011. The plugin does not do anything, it is simply an empty `Execute` method attached on the Post-Process event of the `Account` entity.

My plugin looks like this:

```
namespace CrmDemo.Plugins
{
    public class PostAccountCreateDetail: IPlugin
    {
        public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

The plugin registers fine; here is what the registration screen looks like:
[image: plugin registration]

When I create a new account, I receive the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: The plug-in type could not be found in the plug-in assembly: CrmDemo.Plugins.PostAccountCreateDetailDetail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
    <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
    <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic" />
    <Message>System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: The plug-in type could not be found in the plug-in assembly: CrmDemo.Plugins.PostAccountCreateDetail</Message>
    <Timestamp>2014-08-14T15:29:09.9661308Z</Timestamp>
    <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
    <TraceText>

    [CrmDemo.Plugins: CrmDemo.Plugins.PostAccountCreateDetail]
    [3e3c27ae-c723-e411-bdf4-00155d1e0a3f: CrmDemo.Plugins.PostAccountCreateDetail: Create of account]


    </TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

Here is the error log:

```
[2014-08-14 14:11:31.100] Process: w3wp |Organization:d39e4ccc-fc01-4c27-824d-9106d1ec082e |Thread:   22 |Category: Exception |User: 6abf3aac-971d-e411-aded-00155d1e0a3f |Level: Error |ReqId: 5c0dd2c9-f20d-4ebb-b9ff-3b8698a15c4d | CrmException..ctor  ilOffset = 0x7
    at CrmException..ctor(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 errorCode, Boolean isFlowControlException)  ilOffset = 0x7
    at CrmException..ctor(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 errorCode)  ilOffset = 0x5
    at ExceptionConverter.TryConvertToCrmExceptionInternal(Exception exception, CrmException& crmException)  ilOffset = 0x81
    at ExceptionConverter.TryConvertToCrmException(Exception exception, CrmException& crmException)  ilOffset = 0xAE
    at SandboxCodeUnit.Execute(IExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x116
    at V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0xE5
    at VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x65
    at Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x65
    at MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x1FB
    at InternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0xE4
    at ExtensiblePlatformMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext pluginContext)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at ExtensiblePlatformMessageDispatcher.CreateWithInvocationSource(BusinessEntity entity, Int32 invocationSource, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0xB4
    at BusinessProcessObject.Create(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x4E
    at AccountService.Create(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0xB
    at RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)  ilOffset = 0xFFFFFFFF
    at RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)  ilOffset = 0x25
    at RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)  ilOffset = 0x89
    at LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)  ilOffset = 0x4F
    at InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)  ilOffset = 0x57
    at V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x50
    at VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x65
    at Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x65
    at MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x1C5
    at InternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0xE4
    at ExternalMessageDispatcher.ExecuteInternal(IInProcessOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory, IPlatformMessageDispatcherFactory dispatcherFactory, String messageName, String requestName, Int32 primaryObjectTypeCode, Int32 secondaryObjectTypeCode, ParameterCollection fields, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId, Guid transactionContextId, Int32 invocationSource, Nullable`1 requestId, Version endpointVersion)  ilOffset = 0x156
    at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, UserAuth userAuth, Guid targetUserId, Boolean traceRequest, OrganizationContext context, Boolean returnResponse)  ilOffset = 0x145
    at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)  ilOffset = 0x3D
    at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)  ilOffset = 0x24
    at InprocessServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request)  ilOffset = 0x34
    at PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal()  ilOffset = 0xF6
    at CreateCommand.Execute()  ilOffset = 0xC
    at EntityProxy.Create(Boolean performDuplicateCheck, Guid auditingTransactionId)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at EntityProxy.Create(Boolean performDuplicateCheck)  ilOffset = 0x7
    at AppForm.SaveEntity(EntityProxy entity, FormEventId eventType, String redirectPath, Boolean performDuplicateCheck)  ilOffset = 0x28
    at AppForm.FormSaveAndCloseEvent()  ilOffset = 0x18
    at AppForm.RaiseDataEvent(FormEventId eventId)  ilOffset = 0xD7
    at EndUserForm.Initialize(Entity entity)  ilOffset = 0x1F
    at CustomizableForm.Execute(Entity entity, FormDescriptor fd)  ilOffset = 0x62
    at AccountRecordPageHandler.ConfigureFormHandler()  ilOffset = 0x56
    at RecordPageHandler.ConfigureFormWrapper()  ilOffset = 0xC
    at GenericEventProcessor.RaiseEvent(String eventName)  ilOffset = 0x2D
    at PageManager.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)  ilOffset = 0x47
    at Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()  ilOffset = 0x54
    at Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  ilOffset = 0x6D3
    at Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  ilOffset = 0x3C
    at Page.ProcessRequest()  ilOffset = 0x14
    at Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)  ilOffset = 0x33
    at CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()  ilOffset = 0x18D
    at HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)  ilOffset = 0x15
    at ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)  ilOffset = 0x10A
    at HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)  ilOffset = 0x5C
    at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)  ilOffset = 0x16A
    at ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)  ilOffset = 0x4B
>Crm Exception: Message: Assembly should be provided, ErrorCode: -2147204719
[2014-08-14 14:11:35.029] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   22 |Category: Exception |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 5c0dd2c9-f20d-4ebb-b9ff-3b8698a15c4d | CrmException..ctor  ilOffset = 0x7
    at CrmException..ctor(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 errorCode, Boolean isFlowControlException)  ilOffset = 0x7
    at CrmException..ctor(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 errorCode)  ilOffset = 0x5
    at ExceptionConverter.TryConvertToCrmExceptionInternal(Exception exception, CrmException& crmException)  ilOffset = 0x81
    at ExceptionConverter.TryConvertToCrmException(Exception exception, CrmException& crmException)  ilOffset = 0xAE
    at SandboxCodeUnit.Execute(IExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x116
    at V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0xE5
    at VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x65
    at Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x65
    at MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x1FB
    at InternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0xE4
    at ExtensiblePlatformMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext pluginContext)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at ExtensiblePlatformMessageDispatcher.CreateWithInvocationSource(BusinessEntity entity, Int32 invocationSource, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0xB4
    at BusinessProcessObject.Create(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x4E
    at AccountService.Create(IBusinessEntity entity, ExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0xB
    at RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)  ilOffset = 0xFFFFFFFF
    at RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)  ilOffset = 0x25
    at RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)  ilOffset = 0x89
    at LogicalMethodInfo.Invoke(Object target, Object[] values)  ilOffset = 0x4F
    at InternalOperationPlugin.Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)  ilOffset = 0x57
    at V5PluginProxyStep.ExecuteInternal(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x50
    at VersionedPluginProxyStepBase.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x65
    at Pipeline.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x65
    at MessageProcessor.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0x1C5
    at InternalMessageDispatcher.Execute(PipelineExecutionContext context)  ilOffset = 0xE4
    at ExternalMessageDispatcher.ExecuteInternal(IInProcessOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory, IPlatformMessageDispatcherFactory dispatcherFactory, String messageName, String requestName, Int32 primaryObjectTypeCode, Int32 secondaryObjectTypeCode, ParameterCollection fields, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken originToken, UserAuth userAuth, Guid callerId, Guid transactionContextId, Int32 invocationSource, Nullable`1 requestId, Version endpointVersion)  ilOffset = 0x156
    at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType, UserAuth userAuth, Guid targetUserId, Boolean traceRequest, OrganizationContext context, Boolean returnResponse)  ilOffset = 0x145
    at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.ExecuteRequest(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)  ilOffset = 0x3D
    at OrganizationSdkServiceInternal.Execute(OrganizationRequest request, CorrelationToken correlationToken, CallerOriginToken callerOriginToken, WebServiceType serviceType)  ilOffset = 0x24
    at InprocessServiceProxy.ExecuteCore(OrganizationRequest request)  ilOffset = 0x34
    at PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal()  ilOffset = 0xF6
    at CreateCommand.Execute()  ilOffset = 0xC
    at EntityProxy.Create(Boolean performDuplicateCheck, Guid auditingTransactionId)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at EntityProxy.Create(Boolean performDuplicateCheck)  ilOffset = 0x7
    at AppForm.SaveEntity(EntityProxy entity, FormEventId eventType, String redirectPath, Boolean performDuplicateCheck)  ilOffset = 0x28
    at AppForm.FormSaveAndCloseEvent()  ilOffset = 0x18
    at AppForm.RaiseDataEvent(FormEventId eventId)  ilOffset = 0xD7
    at EndUserForm.Initialize(Entity entity)  ilOffset = 0x1F
    at CustomizableForm.Execute(Entity entity, FormDescriptor fd)  ilOffset = 0x62
    at AccountRecordPageHandler.ConfigureFormHandler()  ilOffset = 0x56
    at RecordPageHandler.ConfigureFormWrapper()  ilOffset = 0xC
    at GenericEventProcessor.RaiseEvent(String eventName)  ilOffset = 0x2D
    at PageManager.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)  ilOffset = 0x47
    at Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()  ilOffset = 0x54
    at Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  ilOffset = 0x6D3
    at Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  ilOffset = 0x3C
    at Page.ProcessRequest()  ilOffset = 0x14
    at Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)  ilOffset = 0x33
    at CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()  ilOffset = 0x18D
    at HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)  ilOffset = 0x15
    at ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)  ilOffset = 0x10A
    at HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)  ilOffset = 0x5C
    at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)  ilOffset = 0x16A
    at ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)  ilOffset = 0x4B
>Crm Exception: Message: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: The plug-in type could not be found in the plug-in assembly: CrmDemo.Plugins.PostAccountCreateDetail, ErrorCode: -2147220970
[2014-08-14 14:11:35.031] Process: w3wp |Organization:d39e4ccc-fc01-4c27-824d-9106d1ec082e |Thread:   22 |Category: Sandbox |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 5c0dd2c9-f20d-4ebb-b9ff-3b8698a15c4d | SandboxCodeUnit.Execute  ilOffset = 0x116
>Execute: CrmException: CrmDemo.Plugins, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a1e5ef8c26cb80d2; 80040216; System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>Parameter name: The plug-in type could not be found in the plug-in assembly: CrmDemo.Plugins.PostAccountCreateDetail
[2014-08-14 14:11:35.032] Process: w3wp |Organization:d39e4ccc-fc01-4c27-824d-9106d1ec082e |Thread:   22 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 5c0dd2c9-f20d-4ebb-b9ff-3b8698a15c4d | MessageProcessor.Execute  ilOffset = 0x1FB
>MessageProcessor fail to process message 'Create' for 'account'.
[2014-08-14 14:11:35.034] Process: w3wp |Organization:d39e4ccc-fc01-4c27-824d-9106d1ec082e |Thread:   22 |Category: Platform |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 5c0dd2c9-f20d-4ebb-b9ff-3b8698a15c4d | MessageProcessor.Execute  ilOffset = 0x1C5
>MessageProcessor fail to process message 'Create' for 'account'.
[2014-08-14 14:11:35.035] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   22 |Category: Exception |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 5c0dd2c9-f20d-4ebb-b9ff-3b8698a15c4d | CrmException..ctor  ilOffset = 0x7
    at CrmException..ctor(String message, Exception innerException, Int32 errorCode, Boolean isFlowControlException)  ilOffset = 0x7
    at CrmException..ctor(String message, Int32 errorCode)  ilOffset = 0x5
    at PlatformCommand.CreateCrmExceptionFromServiceFault(FaultException`1 fe)  ilOffset = 0x1B
    at PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal()  ilOffset = 0xF6
    at CreateCommand.Execute()  ilOffset = 0xC
    at EntityProxy.Create(Boolean performDuplicateCheck, Guid auditingTransactionId)  ilOffset = 0x0
    at EntityProxy.Create(Boolean performDuplicateCheck)  ilOffset = 0x7
    at AppForm.SaveEntity(EntityProxy entity, FormEventId eventType, String redirectPath, Boolean performDuplicateCheck)  ilOffset = 0x28
    at AppForm.FormSaveAndCloseEvent()  ilOffset = 0x18
    at AppForm.RaiseDataEvent(FormEventId eventId)  ilOffset = 0xD7
    at EndUserForm.Initialize(Entity entity)  ilOffset = 0x1F
    at CustomizableForm.Execute(Entity entity, FormDescriptor fd)  ilOffset = 0x62
    at AccountRecordPageHandler.ConfigureFormHandler()  ilOffset = 0x56
    at RecordPageHandler.ConfigureFormWrapper()  ilOffset = 0xC
    at GenericEventProcessor.RaiseEvent(String eventName)  ilOffset = 0x2D
    at PageManager.OnPreRender(EventArgs e)  ilOffset = 0x47
    at Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()  ilOffset = 0x54
    at Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  ilOffset = 0x6D3
    at Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)  ilOffset = 0x3C
    at Page.ProcessRequest()  ilOffset = 0x14
    at Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)  ilOffset = 0x33
    at CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()  ilOffset = 0x18D
    at HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)  ilOffset = 0x15
    at ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)  ilOffset = 0x10A
    at HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData)  ilOffset = 0x5C
    at HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr)  ilOffset = 0x16A
    at ISAPIRuntime.ProcessRequest(IntPtr ecb, Int32 iWRType)  ilOffset = 0x4B
>Crm Exception: Message: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: The plug-in type could not be found in the plug-in assembly: CrmDemo.Plugins.PostAccountCreateDetail, ErrorCode: -2147220970
[2014-08-14 14:11:35.037] Process: w3wp |Organization:d39e4ccc-fc01-4c27-824d-9106d1ec082e |Thread:   22 |Category: Application |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: 5c0dd2c9-f20d-4ebb-b9ff-3b8698a15c4d | ErrorInformation.LogError  ilOffset = 0x17
>MSCRM Error Report:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: The plug-in type could not be found in the plug-in assembly: CrmDemo.Plugins.PostAccountCreateDetail

Error Number: 0x80040216

Error Message: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: The plug-in type could not be found in the plug-in assembly: CrmDemo.Plugins.PostAccountCreateDetail

Error Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: The plug-in type could not be found in the plug-in assembly: CrmDemo.Plugins.PostAccountCreateDetail

Source File: Not available

Line Number: Not available

Request URL: http://localhost/MartinandAssociates/userdefined/edit.aspx?etc=1&pagemode=iframe

Stack Trace Info: [CrmException: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: The plug-in type could not be found in the plug-in assembly: CrmDemo.Plugins.PostAccountCreateDetail]
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.PlatformCommand.XrmExecuteInternal()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.ServiceCommands.CreateCommand.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.EntityProxy.Create(Boolean performDuplicateCheck, Guid auditingTransactionId)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Platform.EntityProxy.Create(Boolean performDuplicateCheck)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Application.Forms.AppForm.SaveEntity(EntityProxy entity, FormEventId eventType, String redirectPath, Boolean performDuplicateCheck)
```

Looking at the CrmDemo.Plugins.dll file in DotPeek, I can clearly see the `PostAccountCreateDetail` class, so I'm not sure why CRM says it can't find it.

Comment: I think that is just unfortunate editing

It's saying The plug-in type could not be found in the plug-in assembly: CrmDemo.Plugins.PostAccountCreateDetail Detail:<detail of the exception>

See how the second error just says:
  CrmDemo.Plugins.PostAccountCreateDetail

As to why you are getting that error is hard to tell, is there anything in the trace logs?

Comment: I added the crm error trace file to the original post.

Comment: is this registered in sandbox mode? have you tried registering in normal mode? The error log doesn't give much of a clue

Comment: This is registered in sandbox mode and stored in database mode. When trying to register in 'none' mode, I get the following exception: Unable to load the plugin type: CrmDemo.Plugins.PostAccountCreateDetail

Comment: The screen shot of the plugin registration tool looks like the CRM 2013 version. Are you sure you have developed your plugin with the right version of the sdk?

Comment: Hey Dan, did you get a resolution to this?

Answer (score 2):

This could be the problem of dll versions you included...
Check for **(Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk and Microsoft.Crm.Sdk)** version are they 5.0.0.0 or 6.0.0.0 ?
it looks like CRM doesn’t have them in the GAC yet