# Dynamics CRM 2015 - The plug-in type could not be found

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I'm having a very similar problem to:

[Dynamics CRM 2011 - The plug-in type could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25312607/dynamics-crm-2011-the-plug-in-type-could-not-be-found)

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: The plug-in type could not be found in the plug-in assembly: Enlighten.CRM.Customisations.Job.CreateJobDetail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>CallStack</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxAppDomainHelper.Execute(IServiceEndpointNotificationService serviceBusService, IOrganizationServiceFactory organizationServiceFactory, String pluginTypeName, String pluginConfiguration, String pluginSecureConfig, IPluginExecutionContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxAppDomainHelper.Execute(IServiceEndpointNotificationService serviceBusService, IOrganizationServiceFactory organizationServiceFactory, String pluginTypeName, String pluginConfiguration, String pluginSecureConfig, IPluginExecutionContext requestContext)
   at Microsoft.Crm.Sandbox.SandboxWorker.Execute(SandboxCallInfo callInfo, SandboxPluginExecutionContext requestContext, Guid pluginAssemblyId, Int32 sourceHash, String assemblyName, Guid pluginTypeId, String pluginTypeName, String pluginConfiguration, String pluginSecureConfig, SandboxRequestCounter&amp; workerCounter)</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  </ErrorDetails>
  <Message>System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: The plug-in type could not be found in the plug-in assembly: Enlighten.CRM.Customisations.Job.CreateJob</Message>
  <Timestamp>2015-07-23T23:32:27.2903692Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>

[Enlighten.CRM.Customisations.Job.Deploy: Enlighten.CRM.Customisations.Job.CreateJob]
[d2c5efd5-452b-e511-80c4-00155d00461a: Opportunity Create]


</TraceText>
</OrganizationServiceFault>
```

This is an existing plugin that I have working in CRM 2011. The main difference is that I've updated the SDK to be against 7.0.0.1 using the nuget package.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.Extensions/7.0.0.1

The previous question suggested that it was version differences but as far as I can tell my deployment is a newer version if anything (as seen below in the deployment manager below) so the SDK version shouldn't be a problem.

[image: Organisation version]

Any ideas?

Comment: On which version of Dynamics CRM is your plugin installed, 2011 or 2015? In your question you are mentioning 2011, but you tagged your question with `dynamics-crm-2015`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use the assemblies provided in the respective SDK of the version of your CRM.

If you are deploying the plugin to a CRM 2011 environment you should still use assemblies supplied in the 2011 SDK. (i.e. version 5.*.*.*)

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing? CRM2015 is v7.0.*

Comment: I understand now. My next suggestion would be to inspect the CreateJobDetail Plugin's properties in Plugin Registration Tool. Check if both FriendlyName and Name values are present.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like an issue with the isolation mode and/or loading the dependent dll's correctly.

If you are using **Sandbox** isolation mode when registering the plugin, you need to make sure you merge any dependencies with [ilmerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) before registering the plugin assembly.

If you have an isolation mode of **none**, make sure the assembly is in the **GAC** or placed in the **bin\assembly** folder in the CRM installation directory on the server.